# Can´t create more than one content type group

Tags: organic-groups, 7, entities

I am using Drupal commons for a community social network. I am trying to create a second group based on a content type named Leagues. In order to create that group I went to: /admin/structure/types/add, gave the group a name and selected the group check box (as the example given on this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2014777).

But for some reason every time I try to create a new league and save it, I get this error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property `field_og_subscribe_settings`. in `EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()` (line 335 of /home2/jane/public_html/devpage/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

It seems that the field field_og_subscribe_settings is attached to the content type group which I am not exactly sure what it means, but it seems I can´t create more than one group based on a content type.

Comment: Hello and welcome. We provide answers, not "guidance" etc, so please ask your question in a way that makes perfectly clear what you are asking. For example "what should I do to create ... groups based on ... when ...?"

Comment: Cool, I will keep that in mind for my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this solves your issue : [EntityMetadataWrapperException](https://www.drupal.org/node/2316119)

You probably need to add field_og_subscribe_settings field to your new content group type, and make it required.

You can take a look at

`/admin/structure/types/manage/group/fields/field_og_subscribe_settings`

to see how it's been configured for the default group content type.

Refer this link for detailed details about this issue: [EntityMetadataWrapperException errors due to features not being reverted](https://www.drupal.org/node/2065381)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response. I tried adding the field_og_subscribe_settings to my new group but it seems I can´t duplicate that field since the default group content type already has it.... I wonder how the guy from the Drupal forum did it....

Comment: follow the same procedure and add group access field

Comment: ok, I am doing it again, be back in 10 mins. Thanks

Comment: OK, I got it!. I added the new existing field and now everything is working. Thank you Pravin!!!